# Scala string to Char

Tags: scala, char

With Scala 2.12, I am trying to find index of the 1st capitalized letter from a string. Below is my code.

```
"strCapit".split("").indexWhere(_.toCharArray.head.isUpper)
```

or

```
"strAfte".split("").flatMap(x=>x.toCharArray).indexWhere(_.isUpper)
```

isUpper is used on character instead of string. So is there a way of converting elements from a collection from string directly to char as I am not able to do `map(x=>x.toChar)`

Comment: Can't you just call `indexWhere` on the `String` directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
scala> "strCapiT".indexWhere(_.isUpper)
res1: Int = 3

scala> "str".indexWhere(_.isUpper)
res2: Int = -1
```